# Jquery visible for SVG reveal

Tags: jquery, svg

I'm trying to animate revealing SVG lines when scrolling down a page. I'm using jquery-visible to start the animation when in user viewport, but I can't see to manage to animate more than the initial one. Is this the best approach?

```
var path = document.querySelector('.animate, .animate2');
var length = path.getTotalLength();
// Clear any previous transition
path.style.transition = path.style.WebkitTransition = 'none';
// Set up the starting positions
path.style.strokeDasharray = length + ' ' + length;
path.style.strokeDashoffset = length;
// Trigger a layout so styles are calculated & the browser
// picks up the starting position before animating
path.getBoundingClientRect();
// Define our transition
path.style.transition = path.style.WebkitTransition =
  'stroke-dashoffset 2s ease-in-out';
// Go!
jQuery(window).scroll(function() {

  if (jQuery('.animate').visible() ) {
        path.style.strokeDashoffset = '0';
  if (jQuery('.animate2').visible() ) {
        path.style.strokeDashoffset = '0';
}
  })
```

Comment: Well querySelector returns one thing. Perhaps you want querySelectorAll and then to loop over its results.

Comment: Okay, tried with querySelectorAll. I get a warning path.gettotallength is not a function. How do i loop over results? Sorry, it's probably a beginners question, am new to this..

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll see the forEach example in there.